# Disabling transcribe for Expresso store pages

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, transcribe

Wondering if there is a way to disable or redirect Transcribe to the english version of Expresso Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to force your english translation in all of your store templates. Lets for example say you have a header that is shared across all of your templates and that your store templates are in a group called `shop`. Also lets assume that your English translation has an ID of `1` and a name of `english`.

In your header template you would be able to simply add:

```
{if segment_1 == "shop"}
 {exp:transcribe:language name="english"}
  {!-- Alternatively you could use --
   {exp:transcribe:language id="1"}
  --}
{/if}
```

> Sets the language to be used from the template. This can be used to
>   override the default behavior of Transcribe which is to figure out
>   what language to load automatically.

Full documentation for the tag can be found in the 3rd item on [EEHarbor](http://eeharbor.com/transcribe/documentation#tag-reference).

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks Justin. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.6.1 of transcribe you can now use transcribe="disable" in your channel entries tag to force the default language for all.